# how to make regular expression for nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx, regular-expressions

i wrote

```
rewrite ^/([\w_]+)/?$ /index.php?$1
```

btw, i wanna except /empty.

hmm..

wanna use

```
/alphabet -> alphabet
/emptyABC -> emptyABC

/empty -> not match

/emp -> emp

/emptAB -> emptAB
```

How can I make regular expressions for these?

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ is your friend

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood correctly what you want, but i think you need something like this:

`rewrite ^/(.+)$ $1;`

The `+` will require at least 1 character to be behind the `/`. Then it takes whats behind the leading `/` and redirects to it.

Your examples could also imply that you want to only capture alphanumeric characters, which would be like this:

`rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1;`